# Why Compilation Does Not Fail?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

As expected, C/C++ compilation does fail with "warning: comparison between pointer and integer" for the program below:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
int main(void) { return (int*)42 == true; }
```

But, the compilation does not fail when the `true` literal is changed to `false`. Why?

- Confirmed for: clang-1100.0.33.12, gcc 7.5.0
- Unable to confirm for: g++ 7.5.0

Comment: C and C++ are different languages

Comment: Please don't call this C/C++. **These are two different languages with different restrictions on allowed code**. While C++ is generally considered a superset of C, there's a lot of legacy C stuff that is not allowed or behaves completely different in C++ mode.

Comment: Comparing a junk pointer to a boolean is not a useful operation, and is probably undefined behaviour.

Comment: Please don't add the C++ tag, as mentioned they are different languages. If you want, you can post a separate question for C++. Adding both tags to this question makes the question meaningless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C, the macro `false` is defined as:

```
#define false   0
```

So you're comparing a pointer against 0, which is a valid null pointer constant.

Comment: Please make clear that this answer is for C, as for C++ it is incorrect.

Comment: reminds me a well known anecdote about a programmer, who were leaving a company and at their last day made a change `#define false true` with a commentary "happy debugging fellas"... I got to understand recently, that his name was Isaiah...